# Spring Cloud Stream routing-to channel gives ClassCastException

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I have a functionRouter that routes messages to different functions based on header. These functions in turn process the message and return a result which I need to publish to another topic. But I get this exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.example.airplane.FlightEvent cannot be cast to class [B (com.example.airplane.FlightEvent is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; [B is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer.serialize(ByteArraySerializer.java:19) ~[kafka-clients-3.3.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:62) ~[kafka-clients-3.3.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:1005) ~[kafka-clients-3.3.2.jar:na]
    ... 59 common frames omitted
```

My setup:

application.properties

```
spring.application.name=airplane
server.port=8095

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.planeEventProducer.destination=plane-events


spring.cloud.stream.bindings.flightEventProducer.destination=flight-events
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.landEventProducer.destination=land-events
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.arrivalEventProducer.destination=arrival-events

spring.cloud.stream.output-bindings=replayProducer;planeEventProducer;flightEventProducer;landEventProducer;arrivalEventProducer

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.functionRouter-in-0.destination=plane-events,flight-events,land-events,arrival-events
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.functionRouter-in-0.group=airplane
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.functionRouter-in-0.consumer.concurrency=8

spring.cloud.stream.function.definition=functionRouter;
spring.cloud.stream.function.routing.enabled=true
spring.cloud.function.routing-expression=headers['Type']
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.autoCreateTopics=true
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=localhost:9092
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.replication-factor=1
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.min-partition-count=8
```

AirplaneApplication.java

```java
package com.example.airplane;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder;

import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.function.Function;

@SpringBootApplication
public class AirplaneApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AirplaneApplication.class, args);
    }

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AirplaneApplication.class);

    @Bean("ArrivalEvent")
    public Consumer<Message<ArrivalEvent>> arrivalEventConsumer() {
        return msg -> {
            logger.info("ArrivalEvent consumed: {}", msg.getPayload());
        };
    }

    @Bean("LandEvent")
    public Function<Message<LandEvent>, Message<ArrivalEvent>> landEventProcessor() {
        return landEventMessage -> {
            ArrivalEvent arrivalEvent = new ArrivalEvent(landEventMessage.getPayload().getFlightId()+"-flight", landEventMessage.getPayload().getCurrentAirport());
            logger.info("Publishing ArrivalEvent: {}", arrivalEvent);
            return MessageBuilder.withPayload(arrivalEvent)
                    .setHeader("Type", ArrivalEvent.class.getSimpleName())
                    .setHeader("spring.cloud.stream.sendto.destination", "arrivalEventProducer")
                    .build();
        };
    }

    @Bean("FlightEvent")
    public Function<Message<FlightEvent>, Message<LandEvent>> flightEventProcessor() {
        return flightEventMessage -> {
            LandEvent landEvent = new LandEvent(flightEventMessage.getPayload().getFlightId()+"-flight", flightEventMessage.getPayload().getCurrentAirport());
            logger.info("Publishing LandEvent: {}", landEvent);
            return MessageBuilder.withPayload(landEvent)
                    .setHeader("Type", LandEvent.class.getSimpleName())
                    .setHeader("spring.cloud.stream.sendto.destination", "landEventProducer")
                    .build();
        };
    }

    @Bean("PlaneEvent")
    public Function<Message<PlaneEvent>, Message<FlightEvent>> planeEventProcessor() {
        return planeEventMessage -> {
            FlightEvent flightEvent = new FlightEvent(planeEventMessage.getPayload().getPlaneId()+"-flight", planeEventMessage.getPayload().getCurrentAirport());
            logger.info("Publishing Flight: {}", flightEvent);
            return MessageBuilder.withPayload(flightEvent)
                    .setHeader("Type", FlightEvent.class.getSimpleName())
                    .setHeader("spring.cloud.stream.sendto.destination", "flightEventProducer")
                    .build();
        };
    }

}
```

AirplaneController.java

```java
@RestController
public class AirplaneController {
    @Autowired
    StreamBridge streamBridge;

    @GetMapping("publishPlane")
    public void publishPlane() {
        PlaneEvent planeEvent = new PlaneEvent(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "CITY");
        Message<PlaneEvent> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(planeEvent).setHeader("Type", PlaneEvent.class.getSimpleName())
                .build();
        streamBridge.send("planeEventProducer", message);
    }
}
```

On calling the GET endpoint (publish plane) I get a ClassCastException when `planeEventProcessor` tries to publish to the `flightEventProducer` binding:

```
org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener failed
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.decorateException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2953) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2894) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2860) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.lambda$doInvokeRecordListener$56(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2783) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.observe(Observation.java:559) ~[micrometer-observation-1.10.4.jar:1.10.4]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2781) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2633) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2519) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2171) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeIfHaveRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1526) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1490) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1365) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run$$$capture(CompletableFuture.java:1804) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Failed to execute runnable
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaInboundEndpoint.doWithRetry(KafkaInboundEndpoint.java:75) ~[spring-integration-kafka-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:461) ~[spring-integration-kafka-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:425) ~[spring-integration-kafka-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2880) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder$ProducerConfigurationMessageHandler@24f4760]
    at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:191) ~[spring-integration-core-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.doHandleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:108) ~[spring-integration-core-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73) ~[spring-integration-core-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder$SendingHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:1118) ~[spring-cloud-stream-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.doHandleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:105) ~[spring-integration-core-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73) ~[spring-integration-core-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115) ~[spring-integration-core-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133) ~[spring-integration-core-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106) ~[spring-integration-core-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72) ~[spring-integration-core-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.sendInternal(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373) ~[spring-integration-core-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:327) ~[spring-integration-core-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:297) ~[spring-integration-core-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$FunctionToDestinationBinder$1.doSendMessage(FunctionConfiguration.java:648) ~[spring-cloud-stream-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$FunctionToDestinationBinder$1.handleMessageInternal(FunctionConfiguration.java:637) ~[spring-cloud-stream-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.doHandleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:105) ~[spring-integration-core-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73) ~[spring-integration-core-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115) ~[spring-integration-core-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133) ~[spring-integration-core-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106) ~[spring-integration-core-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72) ~[spring-integration-core-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.sendInternal(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373) ~[spring-integration-core-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:327) ~[spring-integration-core-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:297) ~[spring-integration-core-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187) ~[spring-messaging-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166) ~[spring-messaging-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) ~[spring-messaging-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109) ~[spring-messaging-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.lambda$sendMessage$1(MessageProducerSupport.java:262) ~[spring-integration-core-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.observe(Observation.java:492) ~[micrometer-observation-1.10.4.jar:1.10.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:262) ~[spring-integration-core-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.sendMessageIfAny(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:394) ~[spring-integration-kafka-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.lambda$onMessage$0(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:464) ~[spring-integration-kafka-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaInboundEndpoint.lambda$doWithRetry$0(KafkaInboundEndpoint.java:70) ~[spring-integration-kafka-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:329) ~[spring-retry-2.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:225) ~[spring-retry-2.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaInboundEndpoint.doWithRetry(KafkaInboundEndpoint.java:66) ~[spring-integration-kafka-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't convert value of class com.example.airplane.FlightEvent to class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer specified in value.serializer
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:1008) ~[kafka-clients-3.3.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:952) ~[kafka-clients-3.3.2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory$CloseSafeProducer.send(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:1022) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.doSend(KafkaTemplate.java:729) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.observeSend(KafkaTemplate.java:700) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(KafkaTemplate.java:510) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.outbound.KafkaProducerMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(KafkaProducerMessageHandler.java:528) ~[spring-integration-kafka-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:136) ~[spring-integration-core-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.doHandleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:105) ~[spring-integration-core-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    ... 51 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.example.airplane.FlightEvent cannot be cast to class [B (com.example.airplane.FlightEvent is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; [B is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer.serialize(ByteArraySerializer.java:19) ~[kafka-clients-3.3.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:62) ~[kafka-clients-3.3.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:1005) ~[kafka-clients-3.3.2.jar:na]
    ... 59 common frames omitted
```

Publishing messages using output-bindings and streamBridge works as expected, but using the same output-binding with `.setHeader("spring.cloud.stream.sendto.destination", "output binding name here")` doesn't.

But, instead of using one of the bindings specified in `spring.cloud.stream.output-bindings` when I try to use the function's output binding `PlaneEvent-out-0`, and add `PlaneEvent` to `spring.cloud.stream.function.definition`, it works as expected.

On debugging a little I can see that streamBridge sets the outputContentType correctly (`application/json`).

```java
public boolean send(String bindingName, Object data) {
        BindingProperties bindingProperties = this.bindingServiceProperties.getBindingProperties(bindingName);
        MimeType contentType = StringUtils.hasText(bindingProperties.getContentType()) ? MimeType.valueOf(bindingProperties.getContentType()) : MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON;
        return this.send(bindingName, data, contentType);
    }
```

But, this doesn't seem to be happening with `spring.cloud.stream.sendto.destination` for bindings which are not specified in `spring.cloud.stream.function.definition`.
The correct outputContentType is present in the `BindingPropeties`, but it isn't getting used.

[image]

How can I get around this?

Comment: Basically what you are saying is that the header for content type is not being set when using `spring.cloud.stream.sendto.destination` mechanism. I'll try to reproduce it, but it appears to be a bug, so please file an issue. Also if you do have a reproducible sample or can make one that would greatly speedup the fixing process

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky here's the github issue I created: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2719